# css and html are not linking

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JavaScript Basics</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>JavaScript Basics</h1>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>





h1{
  color: green;
}
```

Here are both my HTML and CSS. I am using the ATOM text editor on my Mac. Whenever I preview HTML it shows JavaScript Basics in the default black color,not in green from my css.

Comment: Have you ensured that your CSS is in a file called `style.css` in the **same folder** as your HTML file?

Comment: Yes and yes both of them are in the same folder.

Comment: Then it sounds like you have a caching issue. I'll write an answer on this :)

Comment: That would be great! Thanks Obsidian Age!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one dude!

---

```
  `<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Small thing dude ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a caching issue. CSS can be a little strange with caching, and while the classic combination `CTRL + F5` works for images, it doesn't work for CSS. The better solution to dealing with caching in CSS is to hold down `SHIFT` while clicking on the refresh symbol.

Obviously, you can include a backslash in the filepath for the CSS reference, or append a version number, such as: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v2 />`.

This version number doesn't 'mean' anything inherently, but can be useful for denoting updates to the CSS, and importantly will be considered a different file by the browser (forcing it to re-load the CSS).

If you have access to a back-end language like PHP, you can also force the browser to refresh the CSS automatically every time the page is loaded with PHP, by appending a timestamp within the link to the CSS file, with something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />
```

Keep in mind that CSS can be 'costly', so once you have finished development, you probably want to allow visitors to cache by removing the timestamp in a production environment :)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Glad to hear this answer solved the problem for you. Please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)